# Test class based on Today's date

Tags: apex, trigger, class, code-coverage, customization

I have a class which uses today's date to do some calculation.
So bascially it checks the current month based on Todays date and do some calcualtion like below:

```
Integer num = System.today().month();

if(num < 3){
    Do some calculation
}else if(num > 3 && num < 6){
    Do some calcualtion
}else{
    do something else
}
```

Now since this calculation is based on today's date so my code coverage is very less.

How can I overcome this problem.

Comment: Make methods in that class based on parameter with type Date. Run that logic with Date.today() in production and with multiple parameters in unit tests

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since we're not allowed to change the system clock, if you have logic where you need to test for different times, you will need a place to "inject" fake data. One easy way to do this would be to use a static variable in your class:

```
@TestVisible static Integer currentMonth = Date.today().month();
```

Then, in your unit test, specify the month you want to use:

```
SomeClass controller = new SomeClass();
SomeClass.currentMonth = 2;
controller.someMethod();
// Verify expected results ...

SomeClass.currentMonth = 5;
controller.someMethod();
// Verify expected results ...

SomeClass.currentMonth = 9;
controller.someMethod();
// Verify expected results ...
```

Comment: Wondering why not generating test data dynamically against current system date.

Comment: @PasanE this specific question and answer addresses code written that explicitly does something different in different months. Therefore, a test without this setup would get different results depending on the month you ran it in. This is really rare, but there are times when you simply can't avoid it (business rules). It's true that should can, and should, use the current date when practical.